# Name of drawing with smooth solid high-contrast shapes

Tags: drawing, style-identification, style

What is the **common** style name of drawings that consist of smooth solid high-contrast shapes with minimal number of details and minimal number of colors used?

Samples:
[image: Sample 1][image: Sample 2][image: Sample 3][image: Sample 4][image: Sample 5]

Answer (score -1):

Abstract Drawing
the drawing with minimum colors

Comment: I think it's [not](https://www.google.by/search?q=Abstract+Drawing+the+drawing+with+minimum+colors&rlz=1C1CHFX_enBY593BY593&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=oL0CVaqvJcb1ULHlgNgD&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ).